# UIAlertAction - "Could not find member 'Default'"

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Swift's [**trailing closure**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_160) syntax to create a `UIAlertAction`. This code compiles and works as expected:

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: title!, style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    if let delegate = self.delegate {
        delegate.myDelegateMethod?()
    }
}
```

However, I want to [**call the delegate method through optional chaining**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-XID_373), so I changed the code to:

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: title!, style: .Default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    self.delegate?.myDelegateMethod?()
}
```

This shows a compiler error on the `let action = …` line:

> Could not find member 'Default'

I posted a [**complete example on Gist**](https://gist.github.com/getaaron/915e0af58cd2de4159dd) which you can paste into a project or playground.

I didn't change the `UIAlertAction` initialization - just the code within the trailing closure - so I'm not sure what's causing this.

Comment: In your case, `self.delegate?.myDelegateMethod?()` returns a `Void?` which does not match the closures return type `Void`. Just add an explicit `return` statement.